# Is this the right way to predict a time series with the stateful LSTM neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm, stateful

I am using LSTM neural networks (stateful) for time series prediction.

I'm hoping that the stateful LSTM can capture the hidden patterns and make a satisfactory prediction (the physical law that cause the variation of the time series is not clear).

I have a time series `X` with a length of `1500` (actual observational data), and my purpose is to predict the future `100`.

I suppose predict the next `10` will be more promising than predict the next `100` (is that right?).

So, I prepare the training data like this (always using `100` values to predict the next `10`; `x_n` denotes the `n-th` element in `X`):

```
shape of trainX: [140, 100, 1]
shape of trainY: [140, 10, 1]
---
0: [x_0,  x_1, ...,  x_99]  -> [x_100, x_101, ..., x_109]
1: [x_10, x_11, ..., x_109] -> [x_110, x_111, ..., x_119]
2: [x_20, x_21, ..., x_119] -> [x_120, x_121, ..., x_129]
                     ...
139: [x_1390, x_1391, ..., x_1489] -> [x_1490, x_1491, ..., x_1499]
---
```

After the training, I want to use the model to predict the next `10` values `[x_1500 - x_1509]` with `[x_1400 - x_1499]`, and then predict the next `10` values `[x_1510 - x_1519]` with `[x_1410 - x_1509]`.

Is this the right way?

After a lot of reading of documents and examples, I can train a model and make the prediction, but the result seems not satisfactory.

To validate the method, I assume that the last `100 (x_1400 - x_1499)` values are unknown, and remove them from `trainX` and `trainY`, then try to train a model and predict them. Lastly, compare the predicted values with the observed values.

Any suggestions or comments will be appreciated.

The time series looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I'm just curious, is this climatological data?

Comment: No. It is astrophysical data. :)  @RaphaelRoth

Comment: My firt thought was TSI (total solar irradiance) or something like that

Comment: Very close! I am so surprised that you even know TSI! Because my current research is related with TSI. Are you major in solar physics?  :) @RaphaelRoth

Comment: I have worked in a related area during my PhD, I also tried to "predict" TSI using a simple AR model: http://www.clim-past.net/9/1879/2013/, see also http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/full_html/2014/02/aa23391-14/aa23391-14.html

Comment: Nice to meet you here! I took a look at your papers (nice work!), it seems that you are dealing with long-term TSI variations and climate change, while I am focused on space-borne measurements of TSI (only about 4 decades) and solar activities. By the way, have you used stateful LSTM for time series prediction?  @RaphaelRoth

Answer (score 4):

Your question is really complexed. Before I will try to answer it - I'll share my doubts with you about is it sensible to use `LSTM` for your task. You want to use a really advanced model (`LSTM` are capable to learn really complexed patterns) to a time series which seems to be relatively easy. Moreover - you have a really small amout of data. To be honest - I would try to train simpler and easier methods first (like `ARMA` or `ARIMA`).

To answer your question - if your approach is good - it seems to be reasonable. Other reasonable methods are predicting all `100` steps or e.g. `50` steps twice. With `10` steps you might come across error cumulation - but still it might be a good method.

As I mentioned earlier - I would rather try easier `ML` method for this task but if you really want to use `LSTM` you may tackle this problem in a following way:

1. Define metaparameters like number of steps ahead you want to predict, the size of input fed to network.
2. Try to use e.g. grid search in order to find the best value of this metaparameters. Evaluate each setup using `k-fold` crossvalidation.
3. Retrain final model using the best metaparameter setup.

You have relatively small amount of data so you may easily find the best values of hyperparameters. This will also show you if your approach is good or not - simply check the results provided by the best solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason I want to use ` stateful LSTM` is because it has not been used in this problem yet, while `ARMA`, `ARIMA`, normal neural networks, and so other methods have already been used by previous researchers. All of the previous results are not very satisfactory. So, the prediction of this time series remains an unsolved problem.

Comment: It is well known that the variations of this time series are dominated by both long-term and short-term causes, but the specific laws are unclear. I am hoping that the `long short-term memory` ability of LSTM is able to capture the laws and predict the future. Maybe I am too optimistic? :)

Comment: The time series may seems easy, but scientists are still unable to predict the next peak (maximum value & date). Note that the x-axis is time, and the y-axis is a physical quantity (the values are from 0 to several hundreds).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of how to find the best metaparameter. :)

Comment: If you don't mind - I'd appreciate an upvote and acceptance of an answer.